# Google Webmasters tools search queries position

Tags: google, google-search-console, search

In my website account on Google Webmasters tools, some search queries show average position 1.0. This make me understand that it should be displayed as the first result. When I search for this query I could not able to find my website's page listed as a result?! In some cases I navigate to the third or the fourth result page and I could not find it!

What are factors that make my website loss its average position for a search query? and when Google webmasters tools updates their values?

Comment: How many impressions does this particular search query have? Are you searching on google.com or a more local domain?

Comment: Some of them has >10 or 12 impressions. I searched it in google.com.eg

Comment: Those values are highly inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it Finally, The position that web masters tools regarded is correct. I find the same or near position in Image search! I mistakenly restricted the value to the web search only!

Comment: Could it be an aggregate of all Google properties, image, web, blog etc?

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering the same thing and never understood that this number included position for different types of searches and was filterable.

Comment: @Drai Never mind you are welcome!